# Converting SQL Server to Access 2007 Database

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I am converting a database from SQL Server to Access, everything works fine, I have created an Access file from the SQL Server database but when I run the program, in some forms, an exception occurs. It is a VB.Net application and when I use SQL statement given below, exception occurs.

Error

> The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect.

Code:

```
SELECT 
   fee.TodayDate AS Date, fee.ReceiptNo, 
   reg.RegistrationNo, reg.FirstName + ' ' + reg.LastName AS Name, 
   class.Class, reg.Category, fee.TotalFees, fee.OldBalance,
   fee.LateFees, fee.Concession, fee.Discount, fee.Scholarship, 
   (fee.TotalFees + fee.LateFees + fee.OldBalance) - 
   (fee.Discount + fee.Scholarship + fee.Concession) AS NetFees,
   fee.AmountReceived, fee.Balance 
FROM 
   txnFeePayment AS fee 
INNER JOIN 
   tbStudentInfo AS student ON fee.StudentID = student.StudentID 
INNER JOIN 
   mstClass AS class ON student.ClassID = class.ClassID 
INNER JOIN 
   tbStudentRegistration AS reg ON student.RegistrationID = reg.RegistrationID 
WHERE 
   (fee.TodayDate BETWEEN @From AND @To) 
   AND (reg.Regular = 'True') 
   AND fee.SessionID = @sessionid
```

Please help me to find what is problem here.. I need quick solution, thanks

Comment: You need to do some troubleshooting yourself. I don't think `@SessionID` is valid syntax in MS Access. Try temporarily removing that and see if you still get the error. Next try by removing all the selected columns and replacing them with `1`. If the error goes away, then that narrows your error down to your columns.

Answer (score 0):

`Name` is a reserved word in Ms Access. You should bracket it like this: `[Name]`